# C — Hex string to literal hex value

Tags: c, string, hex, string-literals

What is the best way (in C) to convert a hex string (of length 16 or less) to a literal hex value? For example...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char hexstring[] = "30f400010000";
    printf("0x%.16x", strtoll(hexstring, NULL, 16));
}
```

...prints `0x0000000000010000`. I need this to print out `0x000030f400010000`.

I'm very new to C, so I may be missing something very obvious. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your `strtoll()` is fine. It's your `%x` that's wrong.

Comment: `long long` is 64 bits on many platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier in your `printf`.
The correct one for type `long long` to print the number in hexadecimal is `%llx`

```
printf("0x%.16llx", strtoll(hexstring, NULL, 16));
```

Comment: Beat you by a minute and you still get the check...I've gotta type even faster. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `strtoll()` is fine. It's your `%x` that's wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char hexstring[] = "30f400010000";
    printf("0x%.16llx", strtoll(hexstring, NULL, 16));
}
```